# CDI 1.1 - Inject Dependent scope in ApplicationScope

Tags: java, cdi

Say I have an `@ApplicationScoped` service class.

```
@ApplicationScoped
class MyCustomerService {
   ...
}
```

I then want to inject a `Connection` object into that service.

```
@ApplicationScoped
class MyCustomerService {
   private final Connection connection;

   @Inject
   MyCustomerService(final Connection connection) {
      this.connection = connection;
   }

   ...
}
```

The `Connection` object is produced by a `@Produces` method, using a DataSource.

```
class ConnectionProducer {
   ...

   @Produces
   Connection getConnection(final DataSource dataSource) {
      return dataSource.getConnection();
   }

   ...
}
```

Will the `Connection` class be proxied? Will CDI invoke the producer method each time I use the `connection` bean (not like RequestScoped, I really mean for each invocation)?

I know I could just `@Inject` the `DataSource`, this is just "learning" how CDI manages scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will CDI invoke the producer method each time I use the connection bean

No. the producer method called once because the default scope is Dependent . your connection lifecyle bounded to MyCustomerService lifecycle

> Will the Connection class be proxied

If the bean is in  @Dependent scope, then the client holds a direct reference to its instance(clientproxy is just created for NormalScope)

but if the bean has decorator or interceptor a proxy will be created(client proxy is not created because there is not any context for selecting bean but another proxy is created for applying decorators and interceptors) I tested this at weblogic application server

Comment: Thanks. Reading the PDF reference standard I understood that a Dependent bean follows the lifecycle of the containing Bean.